# Enable url link in subview of Root view

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

[image]Hi in my app when i was trying to add a link in textview it works perfect.But when i added a subview from IB to Root view it is not recognizing the url link.how to solve this  any help please.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I have a root view(X).In Interface builder i created a subview called aboutview(b).and when i click a button I added a transparent view(hideview).About view is added as a subview to hide view.

Comment: Order is RootView-Hideview-Aboutview

Comment: try this and then down vote this if you get the solution.Can you?

Comment: hideView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
      hideView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.7];
        abtview.frame=CGRectMake(20, 50, 280, 260);
        abtview.layer.cornerRadius=5.0;
        abtview.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        abtview.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
        
        [hideView addSubview:abtview];
        [self.view addSubview:abtview];

Comment: the following image is about view

Comment: The guys who down vote to this post first solve this and then give the down vote.can you.....You know how to click the down vote but don't know how to solve......If you know the read clearly that have wrote and then ..tell me..what thee bledy..f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare the following property for detecting links while defining your UItextView.

> textview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;

Comment: I know this but this does not solve my issue.Try the above coding that what i have used in my app.If you get the solution for this then tell me what are the changes i have to add to my coding.

Comment: In both Ib and in coding have set these properties for textview but they are not working for sub subview

Comment: I need to see you code only then I able to tell exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: above i wrote the coding

Comment: just see below the post.i wrote the coding that happen when i click the button

Comment: aboutview is in IB.and i manually created hide view

Comment: what is abtview in your code, is UITextView connected through IBOutlet in interface builer?

Comment: I have shown the image of one view in above.In that view many names are there. www.asys.mx name is typed in textview.abtview is nothing but the view i have shown above

Comment: its very tough to understand here..could you make sample xcode project and then share it with me then I will try to resolve your issue.